# PostgreSQL: How to store UUID value?

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I am trying to store UUID value into my table using PostgreSQL 9.3 version.

**Example**:

```
create table test
(
   uno UUID,
   name text,
   address text
);

insert into test values(1,'abc','xyz');
```

**Note**: How to store integer value into UUID type?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The whole point of UUIDs is that they are automatically generated because the algorithm used *virtually* guarantees that they are unique in your table, your database, or even across databases. UUIDs are stored as 16-byte datums so you really only want to use them when one or more of the following holds true:

1. You need to store data indefinitely, forever, always.
2. When you have a highly distributed system of data generation (e.g. `INSERTS` in a single "system" which is distributed over multiple machines each having their own local database) where central ID generation is not feasible (e.g. a mobile data collection system with limited connectivity, later uploading to a central server).
3. Certain scenarios in load-balancing, replication, etc.

If one of these cases applies to you, then you are best off using the UUID as a primary key and have it generated automagically:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
   uno     uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
   name    text,
   address text
);
```

Like this you never have to worry about the UUIDs themselves, it is all done behind the scenes. Your `INSERT` statement would become:

```
INSERT INTO test (name, address) VALUES ('abc','xyz') RETURNING uno;
```

With the `RETURNING` clause obviously optional if you want to use that to reference related data.

Comment: Worth mentioning that v4 uuids are not sortable so lead to index fragmentation. Using v4 uuids for primary care is not a great idea - v1 uuids are better as the coding uses a timestamp which is sortable.

Comment: `uuid_generate_v4()` requires installing an extension. You can use `gen_random_uuid()` that comes with PostgreSQL since version 13

Answer (score 3):

It's not allowed to simply `cast` an `integer` into a `UUID` type. Generally, `UUID`s are generated either internally in `Postgres` (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/uuid-ossp.html for more detail on ways to do this) or via a client program.

If you just want unique IDs for your table itself, but don't actually need `UUID`s (those are geared toward **universal** uniqueness, across tables and servers, etc.), you can use the `serial` type, which creates an implicit `sequence` for you which automatically increments when you `INSERT` into a table.